# Bash - File name change Date + 1

Tags: bash, rename

I have around 500 files that I need to rename with the date the report represents. The filenames are currently:

```
WUSR1453722998383.csv
WUSR1453723010659.csv
WUSR1453723023497.csv
```

And so on. The numbers in the filename have nothing to do with the date, so I cannot use the filename as a guide for what the file should be renamed to. The reports start from 02/12/2014 and there is a report for every day of the month up until yesterday (09/04/2016). Luckily as well the filename is sequential - so 04/12/2014 will have a higher number than 03/12/2014 which will have a higher number than 02/12/2014. This means the files are automatically listed in alphabetical order.

There is however a date in the first line of the CSV before the data:

```
As at Date,2014-12-02
```

Now I've checked that I have all the files already and I do, so what's the best way to rename there to the date? I can either set the starting date as 02/12/2014 and rename each file as a +1 date or the script can read the date on the first line of the file (`As at Date,2014-12-02` for example) and use that date to rename the file.

I have no idea how to write either of the method above in bash, so if you could help out with this, that would be really appreciated.

In terms of file output, I was hoping for:

02-12-2014.csv
03-12-2014.csv

And so on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Do you want the files to list in date order still?  So using the names like `WUSR-2014-02-12.csv` (or perhaps `WUSR-20140212.csv`) would give you the date in the name?  You should add the desired output (final file names) to your question (you can edit your question).  Do you need the original number preserved?  How have you checked that you have all the files?  Whatever you did should be giving you some idea about how to get the information you need in a shell script.  What have you tried?

Comment: I've used: head -q -n 1 *.csv > output.csv to check that I have all the file (I used the output CSV and matched it against every date from 02/12/2014 to yesterday and they are all there). I assume that I can use something like this as well for the file renaming (where it takes the first line of each CSV and uses the date there to rename the file), I just don't know how exactly to tie it all together ...

Comment: I never understand why people like the files ordered so that files from 14th Feb 2014 is followed by the file by 14th Feb 2015, and 14th Feb 2016, and then 15th Feb 2014, 15th Feb 2015, 15th Feb 2016, etc.  However, it is a common problem — there must be some reason why, but I'm sure it's mostly subconscious.

Comment: If you're dealing with Access, it behaves a lot better with alphabetical data inputs rather than having to specify the date you're looking for :)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you stick with Y-m-d format for the filename: that will display in the proper cronological order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the answer you need? Assume all the file are under current directory. Do some testings before you do the real operation. The condition is every date string at your cvs file is unique. There will be some files be overwritten otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv
do 
    o=$(sed '1q' $f |awk -F"[,-]" '{print $NF"-"$(NF-1)"-"$(NF-2)".csv"}')
    # should we backup the file?
    # cp $f ${f}.bak
    mv $f $o
done
```